# Home sharing on iPhone: "You don't have permission to access the requested resource "

Tags: iphone, itunes, permission, sharing, home-sharing

I've configured Home sharing to work just fine on my iPad and Apple TV, however for some reason on my phone I get an error pop up saying "You don't have permission to access the requested resource" when trying to play a song.

I can view my library just fine, but I cannot play any songs.

I've set iTunes to share my entire library which seems fine on the other advices.

I've restarted both my phone and PC, and also signed out of home sharing on my phone and signed in again, and also disabled and re-enabled home sharing on my PC.

Running the latest version of both iOS and iTunes.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your phone joining wifi? Or using your carrier for data?

Answer (score 3):

Fix:

1. Sign out of Home sharing:  iOS *Settings > Music > Sign out of Home Sharing*
2. Sign in to Home sharing again, with your Apple ID.
3. Terminate the *Music* app. Double-click the Home button to bring up the iOS app switcher. Swipe the Music app with an upwards motion, to terminate it.
4. Open the *Music* app again. Home Sharing should now be working again. You will have to reindex the contents.

I don't know why this problem exists, but Home Sharing seems to have become increasingly unreliable as Apple post-Jobs appears to divert resources elsewhere.

Comment: Why the downvote? This solution has worked for me multiple times.

Comment: What apple I'd I bought the music using one and icloud is different

Answer (score 0):

When I visit the home office for my company, which has a very restrictive network, I experience this issue when trying to play music from iTunes. What I observed is that if I shut off my wifi and switch to the cell carrier, I am able to listen to music again. My actual solution, knowing that the company firewall was clearly blocking streaming mechanisms, download the music to my phone prior to entering the corporate WiFi.

Answer (score -5):

You might want to try looking into the Apple Discussions boards when you have problems like this, as millions of other Apple users help each out with their problems there.

Jim

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5431643?start=0&tstart=0